# how to fix deprecated :eq selector in jquery 3.4

Tags: javascript, jquery, deprecated, deprecation-warning

As of jQuery 3.4 `:eq` is being deprecated and instead `.eq()` should be used.

Here is a code snippet which has multiple jQuery selectors which are using `:eq`. How can I break multiple selectors to use `.eq()` instead of `:eq`?

```
$(this).find('th.draggable:visible:eq(' + n + ') span,td:visible:eq(' + (g.actionSpan + n) + ') span'));
```

Comment: Chain the selectors? `.find('th.draggable:visible').eq(n).find('...`?

Comment: simpler logic/selectors. Think about what the goal of this code is and how it can be achieved with far less work rather than trying to come up with a 1:1 replacement of an old selector.

Comment: If you show the markup perhaps we can think of a simpler selection?

Comment: ^^^ Depending upon the actual html, a solution could potentially use one of the `:nth-*` css selectors instead of `:eq()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this using [add()](https://api.jquery.com/add/)

```js
const $th = $('th.draggable:visible',this).eq(n);
const $td = $('td:visible',this).eq(g.actionSpan + n);
const $spans = $('span',$th).add('span',$td)
```

Answer (score 0):

To do the logical OR, you select the first elements, then using `add()` you select the second elements to include them in the first's results.

```js
var $secondDivAndSpanInput = $('div').eq(1).find('input').add(
  $('span').eq(1).find('input')
);

console.log( $secondDivAndSpanInput.get() );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><input type="text" name="divs" value="1"></div>
<div><input type="text" name="divs" value="2"></div>
<div><input type="text" name="divs" value="3"></div>

<span><input type="text" name="spans" value="1"></span>
<span><input type="text" name="spans" value="2"></span>
<span><input type="text" name="spans" value="3"></span>
```