# How to pass jquery instance to selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, deprecated, deprecation-warning

How do i use `.eq()` instead of `:eq()`

I want to use something like this -> `$('div').eq(1)`

Here is code snippet of problem

```
$(document).on('click', 'li.trigger div:eq(1) a.ajax img,' +
    ' li.event div:eq(1) a.ajax img', function (event) {
```

Comment: You will not be able to use `eq()` for the child selector.  You will have to use it inside the click event handler to filter the elements then.

Comment: Hmmm... Isn't this identical to [your question from just a few hours ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59791508/how-to-fix-deprecated-eq-selector-in-jquery-3-4)? At the very least, could you use the knowledge gleaned from those answers to *attempt* this one?

Comment: @TylerRoper can you please check it for once because its not identical

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Small dummy version of what you will most likely have to do.  You will want to use the `eq()` inside the event handler, to check that the element for the event matches which ever ones you want.

Edit: The question has changed from the usage of `:eq` to `:first`.  Since `:first` is the same as `:eq(0)`, little about the solution has to change.

```js
$(document).on('click', 'button', e => {
  $('#container').append('<div><p>Click Me</p></div>');
});

$(document).on('click', 'div p', e => {
  if ($('div p').eq(0).is(e.target)) {
    console.log('You clicked the first paragraph!');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
<button>Add More</button>
```

Comment: FWIW, OP has now edited the question to be about `first` instead of `eq`. Implementation seems more or less the same though.

Comment: Yeah, first is the same as eq(0)

Comment: Agreed, which is why I think it's a duplicate of the question OP asked just a few hours ago :)

Comment: The only reason I didn't agree with a vote to close as duplicate was due to the delegate event handler nature.  I felt there was enough of a difference between a straight finder and a child selector to let it slide.

Comment: Makes sense, I won't fight ya on that one. Good answer.

Comment: can we do something like this `$(".sample_list li").eq(0).click(function(){` with `$(document).on('click'`

Comment: If you are not dealing with delegate event bindings, yes.